# How to position an image higher using tabular

Tags: tables, floats

Im wonder, how to position an image higher.

[image]

The previous image, corresponds to this code:

```
\begin{tabular}{m{5.25cm}m{10.5cm}}
\includegraphics[width=48mm]{Screenshot_12.png}
& \begin{center}\textbf{\large{Pricipal Title}}

\footnotesize{Subtitle}

\footnotesize{Another title}

\footnotesize{More things}
\end{center}
\end{tabular}
```

Any idea to place the image in a higher position? I have tried everything but it has not worked.

Comment: you should upload the code in your preamble also

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/read/mkzyjqqwtmbk here is it

Comment: Please prepare a complete minimal working example and include it directly in your question. Please also clarify the meaning of higher position in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you need to raise the contents of the `tabular` environment by 10mm, you could insert the instruction `\vspace*{-10mm}` right before the start of the `tabular` environment.

By the way, `\large` and `\footnotesize` are switches and don't take arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{array} % for 'm' column type

\begin{document}
\vspace*{-10mm} % <-- new
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{} m{5.25cm} m{10.5cm} @{}}
\includegraphics[width=48mm]{Screenshot_12.png}
& \footnotesize
  \begin{center}
    \obeylines % just for this example
    \textbf{\large Principal Title}
    Subtitle
    Another title
    More things
  \end{center}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what i was looking for